# Simulink: changing parameter mid-simulation

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to run a Simulink model with 12 "In" blocks and 4 "out" blocks" using a Matlab script.
[image]

One of those 12 inputs is a variable called `input_boucle` which is initially set at value 0.

I would like the simulation to last 5 seconds and at time = 3 seconds, I want the `input_boucle` variable to switch from 0 to 1 for the remaining of the simulation.

My initial script was quite simple:

```
  t_stop = 5;
  T_s = t_stop/1000;
  options = simset('SrcWorkspace','current', 'fixedstep', T_s) ;
  sim('test_all_InOut_Blocks.slx',t_stop, options);
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
save_mat_file_InOut_blocks; % That's where I create my workspace with all the variables

t_stop_ouverte = 5;
T_s = t_stop_ouverte/1000;
options_boucle_ouverte = simset('SrcWorkspace','current', 'fixedstep', T_s) ;
sim('test_all_InOut_Blocks.slx',t_stop_ouverte, options_boucle_ouverte)
set_param('test_all_InOut_Blocks','SimulationCommand','pause') % But how do I specify to stop at 3 seconds?
input_Boucle.signals.values = double(0); % 1: boucle ouverte, 0: boucle fermée
set_param('test_all_InOut_Blocks','SimulationCommand','continue')
```

I understand that this is the way:
[image]

With the assertion having for command:

```
set_param(bdroot,'SimulationCommand','pause'),
disp(sprintf('\nSimulation paused.'))
```

As advised here: https://fr.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/controlling-execution-of-a-simulation.html

But how can I integrate my inital model to this model?

Would anyone know how to solve my issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd use the [Step](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/step.html) block to specify the intial value, final value and step time. All of these parameters could be set programmatically before model execution

Comment: Alternatively, for this particular input, connect it to a timeseries/dataset variable which changes from 0 to 1 after 3 seconds. https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/simulink.simulationdata.dataset.html